# Parsing comments in dot file with python

Tags: python, graph, dot, pydot

I'm using *pydot* for parsing dot files in python. I can't find a way to parse comments present in the dot file itself, is there any way to do it?

By just looking at the documentation I couldn't find any answer.

Also, would you suggest a better parser for dot files (perhaps better maintained) than *pydot*?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it is possible if you use the module json along with it like:

```
import pydot
import pyparsing
import json


graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_file(path)
edgeList = graph.get_edge_list() 
for e in edgeList:
      tempAttr = json.dumps(e.get_attributes())
      edgeAttr = json.loads(tempAttr)
      edgeAttr['insert_label_here']
```