# Loading and saving graphs in python

Tags: python, graph

I need to create a graph based on a set of input files. Since those files could be loaded during separate iterations, I need to **save the graph** and be able to add to it after **re-loading the graph information from file**.

The obvious choice seems [graphviz](http://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but the python API doesn't seem to allow loading. [PyDot](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot) has a `parse_dot_data` file and is also referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36388704/204634) but the documentation is non-existing and there's no clear way to 'append' to a graph. Then there's [networkX](https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) which seem to have the [ability to load](https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) although it's nowhere in the documentation to be found. Lastly there's [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/index.html) which is overkill and requires more libraries and tool than I need for this simple job.

I'm sure this must be a solved problem and I'm reluctant to "reinvent the wheel" and write a database/persistence layer to accomplish this.

How can I make a simple graph in Python, save it somewhere and load it when needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) provides abundant file formats for reading and writing graphs. Refer to [Reading and writing graphs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/readwrite.html) for the detailed description. For instance,

```
import networkx as nx

# Create a graph
G = nx.florentine_families_graph()

# Save to a file
filename = 'florentine_families_graph.graphml'
G = nx.write_graphml(G, filename)

# Load from a file
filename = 'florentine_families_graph.graphml'
G = nx.read_graphml(filename)
```

Comment: That looks sensible. Obviously I had found that link 2 minutes after writing my post...