# Modify a file structure using scripts

Tags: python, shell, file

I have a file say f1 in the following format:

```
digraph G {
  rankdir=TB;
  node [style="filled", ];
  2 [label="Decl n1", fillcolor="#FFEFD5", shape=box, ];
  3 [label="In1", fillcolor="#6495ED", shape=box, ];
  4 [label="Decl n2", fillcolor="#FFEFD5", shape=box, ];
  5 [label="In2", fillcolor="#6495ED", shape=box, ];
  ...........

  edge [dir=back, ];
  3 -> 2 [color="#000000", style="dotted", ];
  2 -> 3 [color="#000000", style="dotted", ];
  ...........
  }
```

I need to modify it such that each list is reversed and the "," at the end of the list should be removed. For example, the output format should be like:

```
2 [shape=box, fillcolor="#FFEFD5", label="Decl n1"];
```

How do I approach this problem? Do I have to use any scripts? I am not very familiar with shell scripts.

Comment: A library that understands the syntax is the safe place to start. See for instance https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz (note, Python, not shell).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Will I be able to get the graph object from dot file?

Comment: Yes, as described in the answers to [How to parse a DOT file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313901/how-to-parse-a-dot-file-in-python)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, That helped alot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd use something which is aware of the Dot syntax, allowing you to find and fix invalid syntax reliably. There is a [Dot plugin for IDEA](https://github.com/bzixilu/dotplugin) which you could try (use <kbd>F2</kbd> to move to the next problem in the file). For very simple (but risky, since it's not syntax-aware) replacements you can use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/, \]/]/' your-file
```

As for reversing with `sed`, the general pattern would be:

```
sed -i 's/\(first-part\)\(second-part\)/\2\1/' your-file
```

Comment: This only removes the extra "," at the end. It doesn't reverse the list?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the reversal requirement. You can do that by using `sed` with backreferences (`\1` etc).

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I'm not very familiar with sed

Comment: This seems not to work. And what is first-part, second-part?

Comment: The syntax given for `-i` makes this somewhat specific to GNU sed (one could work with BSD `sed`, as on MacOS, by passing an argument for backup filename extension).