# Loading .dot file in graphviz

Tags: python, graphviz, dot

I was looking for a way to create `Digraph` instance using `graphviz` package from existing *.dot* (or *.gv*) file, is that possible?

I want to do that in order to add/change attributes in the graph and then render altered graph.

NOTE:

1) I tried loading *.dot* file using `Source` class, however it does not seem to have methods to change the loaded graph. (Mentioned here [How to parse a DOT file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313901/how-to-parse-a-dot-file-in-python)).

2) I cannot use any other packages (i.e. `pygraphviz`, `pydot` etc.)

3) The *.dot* file contains a correctly formatted graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse the `.dot` source file using ANTLR4 and [this grammar.](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/dot/DOT.g4), and the python binding for ANTLR4.  I use C# myself with ANTLR4 but believe there is a python implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I figured that my project had `pydot` installed, hence I went ahead with it.